# Library builder not triggering on modified file in SCons

Tags: scons

I have to build a target using a two steps compilation.

The first step: .c -> .asm
The second step: .asm -> .o

I am creating a library from some .o files.

My implementation is the following:

The first step:

```
c_to_asm_builder = SCons.Builder.Builder(action = SCons.Defaults.CAction,
                                emitter = {},
                                suffix = '.asm',
                                src_suffix = ['.c','.cpp'],
                                src_builder = '',
                                source_scanner = SCons.Tool.CScanner
                                )
env['Builders']['CTOASM'] = c_to_asm_builder
```

The second step:

```
suffixesASM = ['.asm', '.s']
static_obj, shared_obj = SCons.Tool.createObjBuilders(env)
for suffix in suffixesASM:
    static_obj.add_action(suffix, SCons.Defaults.ASAction)
```

I am then calling the builders as follows:

```
   env.CTOASM(['file1.c', 'file2.c', 'file3.c'], CFLAGS = '-flag')
   env.Object(['file1.asm', 'file2.asm', 'file3.asm'], ASFLAGS = '-flag')
```

I am creating a library like this:

```
env.Library('name', ['file1.o', 'file2.o'])
```

Everything works fine for the compilation.

The problem appers when:

I change file1.c content. I expect file1.c to pass trough these steps:

file1.c -> file1.asm -> file1.o and then name.a library to be recreated.

What happens:

Only c_to_asm_builder is retriggered by the change (file1.c -> file1.asm). The Object builder (file1.asm -> file1.o) is not retriggered and also the Library builder and Program builder are not retriggered.

I don't know what I am missing. I know that for a single step compilation that I configured in another project the Object builder and Library builder are somehow aware of each other.

How to make Library and Program builder aware of Object and CTOASM builders ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying an emitter, so either write one, or explicitly list your expected targets...

```
asm = env.CTOASM(['file1.asm', 'file2.asm', 'file3.asm'], 
                 ['file1.c', 'file2.c', 'file3.c'], CFLAGS = '-flag')
obj = env.Object(['file1.o', 'file2.o', 'file3.o'], asm, ASFLAGS = '-flag')
lib = env.Library('name', obj)
```

Here is a good reference on how to add an emitter to your builder.
https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/ToolsForFools
Just scroll down to "Using Emitters".

Comment: I tried this and I still get the same behavior. Somehow the library builder doesn't link to my object builder.